# Unable to polyfill `Object.fromEntries` using babel/preset-env

Tags: babeljs, vite, babel-preset-env, astrojs

Am I misunderstanding something about or misconfiguring `babel/preset-env`?
I'm using babel configs for vite using `vitejs/plugin-legacy`, but for AstroJS project.

```js
plugins: [
  legacy({
    targets: ['defaults', 'not IE 11', 'ios_saf > 10']
  })
]
```

From my understanding, simply specifying the browserslist query should be enough for babel to generate the appropriate polyfills:

> We leverage these data sources to maintain mappings of which version of our supported target environments gained support of a JavaScript syntax or browser feature, as well as a mapping of those syntaxes and features to Babel transform plugins and core-js polyfills.

If `Object.fromEntries` is not supported in `ios_saf < 12` but is part of the ECMA 2019, why does my test browser (which is ios_saf 11) raise an error for this function?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am facing a similar issue

Comment: Plus one.
Even with the `useBuiltIns: "usage"` this function remains as it is.